# System clock resets after reboot

Tags: linux

I'm writing an application that needs to be able to set the time and date on a debian linux panel. I am able to successfully set both the system time and the hardware clock, but after a reboot the system clock is getting set back to the current time. The hardware clock remains at the time I changed it to prior to the reboot.

The machine this will be running on will not have any network or internet access, so (I think) I have removed NTP, but is there anything else that would be causing this to happen? Is there a way to verify that NTP is NOT running?

I am pretty much a linux newbie, so any assistance anyone can offer is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to commit changes to the clock back to the hardware, you must run the [`hwclock`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hwclock) program:

```
/sbin/hwclock --systohc
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm doing. I set the system clock with the 'date' command and then set the hardware clock to the system clock using the exact command you give here. Afterwards, both the system clock and hardware clock show the time I want when I run 'date' or 'hwclock --show', but then when I reboot, 'date' goes back to the previous time. 'hwclock --show' continues to show the time I wanted to change to.

Comment: Do you have a hardware problem?  Is your RTC getting deactivated somehow?  What kind of hardware is this?

Comment: What's the time delta between the wrong value and the correct time?  Is it strictly hours, like the same offset that your time zone is from UTC?  The value stored in the RTC can be considered as the UTC or local time, depending on configuration.

Comment: It's a small touch panel with an ARM processor: http://www.embeddedarm.com/products/board-detail.php?product=TS-TPC-8390

Comment: No, whether I change time or date, to any value, it always returns to the correct current time. Like there's another clock somewhere resetting it. That's why I thought NTP could still somehow be the culprit.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, but it turns out it was an issue specific to the hardware as I detailed in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Technologic Systems (the hardware manufacturer) and determined this hardware has its own unique function for setting its hardware clock.

"The system clock on the TS-4700 is accessed using ts4700ctl:

ts4700ctl --getrtc # sets the system time from the RTC

ts4700ctl --setrtc # saves the system time to the RTC"

Sorry for thinking it was a Linux issue, but I'm glad I'm not going crazy!